# How to go through pagination with a crawler?

Tags: php

i have made a crawler, but i can´t understand how i can go through a pagination, can someone please help me with this, thanks.

Here is my crawler script:

```
    if(!$fp = fopen("https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topselling_paid&cat=LIBRARIES_AND_DEMO&start=0&num=24" ,"r" )) {
        return false;
    }
    $content = "";

    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $content .= fgets($fp, 1024);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    if (!preg_match('/error-section/i', $content)) {
      preg_match_all("/id=([^/i", $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

      $i=1;
      foreach ($matches as $val) {

          $link = $val[1];

          if(!$fps = fopen("https://market.android.com/details?id=". $link ,"r" )) {
            return false;
          }
          $content_app = "";

          while(!feof($fps)) {
            $content_app .= fgets($fps, 1024);
          }
          fclose($fps);

          preg_match("/([^/i", $content_app, $regs);
          echo $regs[1]. "
;

      }
    }else{
      echo 'Error page not found!';
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a pagination"? Needs more info...

Comment: @Pekka - I'm pretty sure that the OP is wanting to know how they may deal with content that spans over several pages. More information would be nice, but a technique for doing this I would assume doesn't require more information in the abstract.

Comment: @Jared  I think it does - after all, the HTML used for pagination can't be predicted (or the whole might be completely Ajax based). Some more info  is necessary I think. (Downvote isn't mine though)

Comment: Like Jared say, as you can see i want to crawl android market, but my script can only crawl the first page in a category, but i want it to automaticly crawl all pages there is in the category.

Comment: @Jonas - Speaking generally, you'll need to determine how the site increments the display results and crawl to those using some logic (loop? split processes?), and/or determine if links to the paged content within the site can be crawled and find and crawl them.

Comment: @JonasHansen - And if you're trying to crawl by categories, you'll need to find a way to get each category (id, term) and apply those, or crawl links that lead to those category's paged content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the pagination is something similar to comment pagination on blogs.

One way is to find the link to the next page, and follow that link. It can be done quite easily with a regex.

Another way, if you are crawling a single site, is to figure out their url-structure of the pagination, and then just scan pages incrementally until there are no more comments.

Comment: Okay i found their url-structure, in the url start=0 shall just be fx. start=0 if i want apps from 0-24 and fx. start=24 if i want the apps between 25-48. But i can´t figure out how i make my script so i just go to next page when there is no more apps on the current page, can you help with that?

Comment: Ok good. It's a bit hard to give a generic solution, because it depends on the html of the specific page, but (1) but first define a url you want to connect to (2) in a whileloop connect to the url and do the matching (3) if you dont match anything, break out of the loop (4) if you do match something, then do something with the matched stuff, and set the url to the new destination (like example.com?start=24)

Comment: Thanks for the help i found a solution. I find out how many pages there is and then i make a for loop, there is set to the maximum number of pages, i don´t know what ever it´s the best solution or something, but i works :)